# how event loop phases handles the requests?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

Event loop has phases as:

```
   ┌───────────────────────┐
┌─>│        timers         │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐
│  │     I/O callbacks     │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐
│  │     idle, prepare     │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘      ┌───────────────┐
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐      │   incoming:   │
│  │         poll          │<─────┤  connections, │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘      │   data, etc.  │
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐      └───────────────┘
│  │        check          │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐
└──┤    close callbacks    │
   └───────────────────────┘
```

how does it work? does it jump from one phase to another? if yes then when it jumps? or it just maintains the que and executes the one callback after the another? and what is `next tick` , does it mean that when entire que is completed and que is empty then the loop starts over again? is there any actual loop in event loop? and how does this poll phase works? what happens when a new request arrives?

node maintains the worker pool (which are actually c++ threads), and whenever a some I/O task or any other blocking task comes, it hands over that task to that worker thread which actually carries out system task as interacting with database and getting data  and when worker thread completes its task than worker thread puts the callback handler in event que back, and node takes this callback and executes it . Is this correct?

what is nodejs binding(c++)?

how event loop works? does it run on main thread?

Comment: On the [page](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) which is the source of your example diagram, "event loop" is mentioned 37 times. Did that not give you enough context to understand the matter? Do you mean by the overly broad "How does the event loop work?" that someone should expend it for your even further than that 2600 words document? There is no programming problem in this post so it's off topic. Also, please start every sentence with capital letters.

Comment: Agreeing with @marekful, This is not something which can be explained in a StackOverflow answer. And, I have written a detailed series of articles on how the event loop works. https://jsblog.insiderattack.net/event-loop-and-the-big-picture-nodejs-event-loop-part-1-1cb67a182810 You might find it very helpful.